# Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 installation problem

Tags: gnome, hard-drive, uefi

I want to install ubuntu GNOME 15.10 on my computer from USB, but th installer do not detect the drives. When the USB drive is connected, the UEFI do not display my drives as bootable devices. I have now Windows 7 on my computer with a 128GB SSD and a 500GB HDD. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your USB installation media seems to not be properly configured.

Create a working USB drive by using the **disks** tool from within Ubuntu.

Open it and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.

Choose the ISO file and the USB drive to write it to and start restoring.

If you have or want to do it from within Windows use the **diskpart** tool.

Open **command prompt as administator** and execute:

```
diskpart

list disk  
select disk * (* = number of USB drive)  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=** (** = select a free drive letter)
```

Mount the ISO file and copy the content to the USB drive.

Comment: I did it, but not working. It's the same problem.