# How to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I've tried to install Ubuntu twice, after the first time I installed it then I restarted my laptop (as instructed) and it fails to boot Ubuntu saying Ubuntu is on low graphics mode giving me various options of what to do none of which worked.
Same thing happened when I installed the second time.

I had to change my option from UEFI to legacy in my BIOS because I couldn't boot from UEFI.

I just want to know what I'm doing wrong/how to properly install Ubuntu?

Laptop:Lenovo G50
Distro:ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tried to do will not work.
Windows 10 is installed in UEFI (GPT) mode.
You have to install Ubuntu in EFI mode as well.
It is not possible to do this with Ubuntu in 32 bit.
Install the recommended [64 bit edition of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: Was the distro I listed not 64 bit? Becuase it will take a while to download another iso.

Comment: @Dokrzz : No ... ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso is the 32 bit version ... the 64 bit version of Ubuntu is : ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso ! :)

Comment: I tried with a 64 bit distro (ubuntu 15) and nothing changed in regards to UEFI does it have to be specifically that distro you linked.

Comment: @Dokrzz : Yes ... it has to be one of those two (14.04.3 or 15.10) in 64 bit. Boot from the installation media you have created (select the Ubuntu entry with UEFI). When you have further problems, please read this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/688813/ubuntu-gnome-15-10-installation-problem/688819#688819 and - in case you have a dedicated NVIDIA graphics adapter - this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/728551/graphics-broken-after-4-2-0-27-update/728678#728678 ! :)

Comment: Also note that how you prepare your installation media can be important; some tools omit the EFI-mode boot loader, or set it up in such a way that it doesn't work with some computers. If you can't get it to boot in EFI mode, try another tool. [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) generally works well from Windows (you may need to fiddle with some of its options), and [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) generally works from a variety of OSes. Even these may fail with some systems, though.